# Disable the start slash being removed in url rewrites

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Allright so I have a website where I want traffic to go from

```
http -> https
non www -> www
```

So the final url should look like: `https://www.x.net`
I set up some rewrite rules in my htaccess, which look like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

It works fine, everything gets redirected but the only problem is the following type of urls.

```
x.com/help
```

What happens is it will redirect to

```
https://www.x.comhelp
```

It removes the slash between com and help, I couldn't find an answer on Google so that's why I though, maybe my StackOverflow friend could help me out :)

Comment: That slash is _not_ somehow magically removed. It simply is not part of the `${REQUEST_URI}` you use in `.htaccess` style files, since those only work on _relative_ paths. That is different if you place those rules in the http servers host configuration (much better anyway, but you need access). If you want to stick with `.htaccess` style files you have to add it manually: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}$1`. Though this actually depends a little on where that file you use actually is located. You should start reading the documentation. This is explained in there.

Comment: @arkascha The `%{REQUEST_URI}` server variable _does_ contain the slash prefix. It's the URL-path that matches against the `RewriteRule` pattern that does not (the per-directory prefix is stripped).

Comment: "It works fine" - the directives you have posted cannot result in the output as stated. Given a request for `x.com/help`, your current directives would result in: `https://www.x.com/helphelp`. (not `https://www.x.comhelp`).

Answer (score 0):

> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`
>   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]`

You should not use both the `%{REQUEST_URI}` server variable and the `$1` backreference together. Use one or the other, see below...

You would need to change your directives to the following. This uses a backreference to the `RewriteRule` pattern which notably excludes the slash, so this must be included in the substitution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Alternatively, use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` server variable instead. (This includes the slash prefix.)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to a `301` (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK. (301 redirects are cached by the browser, so make sure your caches are cleared before testing.)